# (Web Server) Can't find a folder JavaScript script is successfully reaching

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm working with an HTML file that sends data using AJAX through POST to https://www.example.com/register_email.

If I copy & paste https://www.example.com/register_email in my browser it returns

```
{"status":"error","message":"Please enter Email"}
```

but in FileZilla I'm not able to find anything called "register_email", same goes with my hosting's file manager.

Comment: That would probably a route created by the web service or web server, so a non-existing file. It could be PHP, node, or any other service made with any other server language or even the webserver itself (e.g. nginx). At this point there are so many options that I cannot explain them all or what to do.  Try to find in files for that 'Please enter Email' text and hope for a result. If not, then it might be a route in e.g. nginx

Comment: Who controls www.example.com? Many modern web app frameworks use routing where URI does not always map to a physical file

Comment: example.com is controlled by a friend of mine who asked for my help implementing some functions to the website (I do have credentials to access the domain). The website hosted on example.com has been made by a third party company using PHP with the CodeIgniter framework

Comment: 1) There probably will be no physical "register_email" file. 2) Ther error you from your copy and paste is from a GET request that is missing the "email" parameter, the API may be set up to only recieve POST requests., but I'd expct a different error. Why do you want to find the location for the serverside code? What are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Is the site being requested by AJAX owned by you? If not, since you have no control over the site you won't see anything called "register_email" in your server's directory.

When you past it in the browser you get an error is because

1. browser requests web pages using GET method
2. no data is being passed

Lastly if the domain (to which the request is being sent) is yours, and you still don't see anything called "registered_email" try searching using filezilla or see if there is an htaccess rule for masking the url

Comment: Yeah, the site being requested is mine, data is sent using POST, so it's fair I get the error, the point is that I don't have a clue how I get that error if apparently "register_email" doesn't exist on my web server (but at the same time I get the error which means that register_email exists!). In my AJAX request I do have ""url": '<?=base_url('register_email')?>'", and if I echo "base_url('register_email')" I get https://www.example.com/register_email.